# why my web site don't supported in mobile phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Responsive Images Test Page</title>
</head>
<body> 

 <h1>Responsive Images Test Page</h1>
 <p>In supported browsers, the following image will load either small or large version depending on screen resolution, making a single 1kb request before requesting the appropriate size.</p>

 <img src="sample-content/running-sml.jpg?full=sample-content/running-lrg.jpg" />

 <p id="cred"><strong>Photo credit (CC):</strong> Cia de Foto <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/ciadefoto/3192757134/in/pool-809956@N25/">Flickr Creative Commons</a></p>
 
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to develop a responsive website. but my website don't supported in mobile phone.
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
i used the above tag for responsive website. but this is not working. 
please help me

Comment: Which mobile phone ? All ?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show us any code.

Comment: Best would be to share a link to the site.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: in your mobile phone, make sure the desktop version is not selected?

Comment: What VXp said - adding that meta data just tells the browser how to set up the page display, but it doesn't automagically make the site responsive, you still need to build/stye it responsively. If you have any examples to share we can help with specifics.

Comment: all kind of mobile phones

Comment: do you have any mobile styling?

Answer (score 0):

Responsive Design is something you have to do manually with css. You cannot simply add a meta tag and your page is responsive ;)
For your above code example you can do it inline like this:

```
<img style="max-width:100%" src="sample-content/running-sml.jpg?full=sample-content/running-lrg.jpg" />
```

but of course you should create an stylesheet file for your site.